# Tkinter, scroll other text box to that text contained in text box 1 on click. Is it possible without tag bind?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

DESCRIPTION:

I created 3 textboxes. First and second are populated it with text.
The third is the comparison between the first 2 textboxes.
I used tag_configure to display the differences.

---

QUESTION:

I want that when I click on the sentence or any part of the text in textbox 1 or 2 or 3, it should scroll the other textboxes to that text.

How shall I extract the text on a click?

---

OUTPUT:

When I click 26 on text box 1, it should scroll tb 2 & 3 to that specific text (i.e.: 26).

[image]

---

CODE:

```
import diff_match_patch as dmp_module
import tkinter as tk

k1 = []
k2=[]
for i in range(100):
    k1.append(" This is the " + str(i) + " document\n")
    k2.append(" This is the " + str(i+5) + " doc\n")

diff = []    
for i in range(len(k1)):    
    dmp = dmp_module.diff_match_patch()
    diff.append(dmp.diff_main(k1[i], k2[i]))
    (dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff))

root = tk.Tk()
journal2 = tk.Text(root, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0,  width = 45, height = 30)
journal2.insert("end","Textbox 1\n\n\n")
journal2.insert("end","\n".join(k1))
journal2.pack(side = 'left')

journal3 = tk.Text(root, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0,  width = 45, height = 30)
journal3.insert("end","Textbox 2\n\n\n")
journal3.insert("end","\n".join(k2))
journal3.pack(side = 'left')

journal1 = tk.Text(root, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0,  width = 45, height = 30)
journal1.insert("end","Textbox 3\n\n\n")
journal1.pack(side = 'left')

journal1.tag_config('insert', foreground="navy", font='Courier 10 bold')
journal1.tag_config('delete', foreground="red2", overstrike=True, )

def add_hyperlink2(section, tag2):
    journal1.insert("end",section,('delete', tag2))

def add_hyperlink3(section, tag2):
    journal1.insert("end",section,('insert', tag2))

def add_hyperlink4(section, tag2):
    journal1.insert("end",section, tag2)

for y in range(len(diff)):
    for q in range(len(diff[y])):
        if diff[y][q][0] == -1:
            add_hyperlink2(diff[y][q][1], diff[y][q][1])

        elif diff[y][q][0] == 1:
            add_hyperlink3(diff[y][q][1], diff[y][q][1])

        else:
            add_hyperlink4(diff[y][q][1], diff[y][q][1])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tag_bind with a closure is by far the easiest. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: because I am tagging a paragraph of text. I want the ability to scroll on sentences and not paragraphs.
And I am inserting text into textbox dynamically, so I am not able to bind a tag to an individual sentence, all I can bind is to a paragraph. So while scrolling, it searches for the paragraph, and not sentences.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. Tkinter has no limitations with respect to tagging sentences vs paragraphs. Why do you think you aren't able to bind a tag to a sentence?

Comment: Are the text widgets guaranteed to have the same number of lines? Does it matter that the user clicks "26", rather than the word "document" after the number "26"? What should happen if they click something other than a number?

Comment: No, the text widgets will have a different number of lines. And it does not have to be specific a number, in fact, it will be a text, when I click on a text, it should search for that text in other versions, and scroll to that specific text.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Will that be possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Tkinter gives you all the tools to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How shall I extract the text on a click?

If you bind to the mouse button click, the event object that is passed to the callback has the x/y coordinates of where the click occurred. You can use that to get the index of the line that was clicked on. If you bind to the *release* of the button, then the text widget will have updated the insertion cursor and you can use that to know what line was clicked on.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click(event):
    index = text.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))
    line, char = index.split(".")
    label1.configure(text="Click on line %s" % line)

def on_click_release(event):
    index = text.index("insert")
    line, char = index.split(".")
    label2.configure(text="Click Release on line %s" % line)

root = tk.Tk()

label1 = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")
label2 = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")
text = tk.Text(root)
label1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
label2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(1, 20):
    text.insert("end", "line #%s\n" % i)

text.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", on_click)
text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_click_release)

root.mainloop()
```

When you run the above code, if you click and hold the mouse button over a line, the line number will appear at the top using the x/y coordinates. When you release the button, the line number will appear using the `insert` index.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. But, in the above code, the number (line number) is extracted. The index that is obtained gives the line number. If I want to extract the word by fetching the xy coordinate, will that be possible?

Comment: @RajMehta: of course. You can extract the test from that line, and use normal python tools for searching that text for a number.

Comment: Can you give an example? Do I need to fetch the index and then from that index to the next white space, extract the word?

Comment: I tried reading the documentation. It says using the coordinate, you can extract the closest word near the mouse pointer using "@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y). But that is still giving the index no. and not the word. I used index = text.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y));      print(index) to try to find the text.

Comment: I want something that exactly to the sel.first method. I select a word and use that word for further processing.

Comment: I got it. First, we fetch the index. And then split it and increase the column by 50 or 20 (any amount) which will be the end index and use the .get() method to extract the text.

Comment: @RajMehta: instead of arbitrarily increasing the column number You can append `lineend` to an index to get to the end of the line (eg: `4.0 lineend` represents the end of line 4)

Comment: How can I use the lineend in the index? I am already passing the relative position of the mouse cursor to the index function, and then when I am adding the lineend arguement as a string, it throws an error saying """index() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given""".

Comment: @RajMehta `end_of_line = text.index("@%s,%s lineend" % (event.x, event.y))`

Comment: Thank you Bryan. This really helped.